# How to create Subdomain in DigitalOcean Ubuntu-22-Cloudpanel?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, digital-ocean, vps

I am constantly trying to connect subdomain and I have also added cname in dns records but still can't get to see the data on screen and then I found we need to edit conf file to redirect to my subdomain but again I am not able too find that file location where to edit these (:- I have checked site-available but no luck).

I need a guide as an absolute beginner to this field VPS.

Confiquration - [Ubuntu CloudPanel 2 - Ubuntu 22.04 2.1.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 ~1 vCPU
2GB / 50GB Disk]

Comment: Is it possible for you to set the NS of the digital ocean in the name server of the main domain?

Comment: @Hami yes i had set that up earlier but no luck

Comment: @Hami do you know how can i setup apache conf files to redirect to subdomain

Comment: In this file find #With Redirect line and set your subdomain as new.example.com:

sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

##With Redirect
Redirect "^/" "http://new.example.com"

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can do this scenario is following these steps:

1-Set NS of the digital ocean in the main domain name servers.

```
ns1.digitalocean.com
ns2.digitalocean.com
```

2-Add domain in the Network section according to this link:
[Add Domain to digital ocean dashboard](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/dns/how-to/add-domains/)

3-Set A record for a subdomain according to the picture below:
[image: Set A record on subdomain]